# How do you concurrently run 4 if statements in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, concurrency

does anyone know how to run two if statements at the same time in python?

```
for i in range(160):

    luca.speed = 1
    if luca.pos() > nick.pos() and luca.pos() > bob.pos():
        luca.backward(luca.speed + 2)
    if luca.pos() < nick.pos() and luca.pos() < bob.pos():
        luca.forward(luca.speed + 3)

    nick.speed = 1
    if luca.pos() > nick.pos() and bob.pos() > nick.pos():
        nick.forward(nick.speed + 8.5)
    if luca.pos() < nick.pos() and bob.pos() < nick.pos():
        nick.forward(nick.speed)
```

I am trying to make these 4 if statements run at the same time instead of one after the other.

Comment: I see that if the first if statement is true then the second one must be false.  So there can't be any performance benefit to running them both at the same time.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Does none of the given answers answer your question?
If no, then you might have to elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with *at the same time*.

1.) Python (the default python implementation) uses the GIL (global interpreter lock), so you will never execute two python statements on multiple CPUs at the same time.

So performance wise there will be no benefit.

If you just mean, that the fact, the the first if statement might change the values from the if statement and thus render the second check false, then simple caching of values, that you use in your if expression will suffice.

```
for i in range(160):

    luca.speed = 1
    luca_pos = luca.pos()
    nic_pos = nic.pos()
    bob_pos = bob.pos()
    if luca_pos > nick_pos and luca_pos > bob_pos:
        luca.backward(luca.speed + 2)
    if luca_pos < nick_pos and luca_pos < bob_pos:
        luca.forward(luca.speed + 3)

    nick.speed = 1
    if luca_pos > nick_pos and bob_pos > nick_pos:
        nick.forward(nick.speed + 8.5)
    if luca_pos < nick_pos and bob_pos < nick_pos:
        nick.forward(nick.speed)
```

Comment: actually, the GIL is **by process**. So you can (using `multiprocessing` for example) execute two python statements on different CPU at the same time. However, the overheads make this option uninteresting for the OP

Comment: @gregoire I know this, but for the given context this is in my opinion rather irrelevant. as the OP wants to execute 4 tiny if statements at the "same" time . Any code trying to spread this over multiple processes will probably be running slower due to the administrative overhead of creating the processes, executing the if statements and resynchronizing the data.
It would also render the code much more complicated to understand.

But yes you are right,  The python solution for running things at the same time is running multiple processes. The `multiprocessing` module can help with this,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't really want to run those statements in parallel (4 instructions at once), but rather you want single evaluation instead of 4 evals, right?

Right now you in both best case and worst case run 4 if, each with 2 comparisons, so 8 ops each time. Let's try to refactor the code - it needs the assumption that either luca.pos never equals nick.pos, or that we can replace > with >=:

```
luca.speed = 1
nick.speed = 1
if luca.pos() >= nick.pos():
  if luca.pos() > bob.pos():
    luca.backward(luca.speed + 2)
  if bob.pos() > nick.pos():
    nick.forward(nick.speed + 8.5)
else:
  if luca.pos() < bob.pos():
    luca.forward(luca.speed + 3)
  if bob.pos() < nick.pos():
    nick.forward(nick.speed)
```

This is 3 ops in both best and worst case.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier (and clearer) if you separate the position determination from the movement actions using temporary variables:

```
for i in range(160):

    lucaAhead = luca.pos() > nick.pos() and luca.pos() > bob.pos()
    lucaBack  = luca.pos() < nick.pos() and luca.pos() < bob.pos()
    nickBack  = luca.pos() > nick.pos() and bob.pos() > nick.pos()
    nickAhead = luca.pos() < nick.pos() and bob.pos() < nick.pos()

    luca.speed = 1
    if lucaAhead:
        luca.backward(luca.speed + 2)
    if lucaBack:
        luca.forward(luca.speed + 3)

    nick.speed = 1
    if nickBack:
        nick.forward(nick.speed + 8.5)
    if nickAhead:
        nick.forward(nick.speed)
```

*There also seems to be an inconsistency in the movement direction between luca and nick (luca moving backward when ahead but nick still going forward). There is not enough information in the question to determine if that is intended or accidental*